# How do I convert a string 2 bytes long to an integer in python

Tags: python

I have a python program I've inherited and am trying to extend.

I have extracted a two byte long string into a string called pS.

pS 1st byte is 0x01, the second is 0x20, decimal value == 288

I've been trying to get its value as an integer, I've used lines of the form

```
x = int(pS[0:2], 16)  # this was fat fingered a while back and read [0:3]
```

and get the message

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\x01 '
```

Another C programmer and I have been googling and trying to get this to work all day.

Suggestions, please.

Comment: Could youplease show the output of: "print pS"? It's unclear to me why int(pS[0:3], 16) won't work. Do you not have the "0x" prefix?

Answer (score 22):

Look at the [struct](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-struct.html) module.

```
struct.unpack( "h", pS[0:2] )
```

For a signed 2-byte value.  Use "H" for unsigned.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the characters to their character code with `ord` and then add them together in the appropriate way:

```
x = 256*ord(pS[0]) + ord(pS[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct.unpack( "h", pS[0:2] )
```

But it will be in array form

`struct.unpack( "h", pS[0:2] )[0]` this will get the value direct

Answer (score 0):

This is a big-endian two-byte number. If you don't want to use the `struct` module, you can also use `int`. If the input is of type `str`, you'll need to convert it to a `bytes` instance using `bytes(pS, 'utf-8')` first though.

```
num = int.from_bytes(pS, 'big')
```