# Remove '\x' from bytes

Tags: python, replace, binary, byte

I'm currently reading bytes from a file and I want to put two of these bytes into a list and convert them into an integer. Say the two bytes I want to read are `\x02` and `\x00` I want to join these bytes together before I convert them into an integer such as `0x0200` but am having difficulty doing so as I cannot remove the `\x` from the bytes.

I've tried using: `.replace('\\x', '')` though this doesn't work as python treats the bytes as one object rather than a list. I've also considered using struct although I'm unsure whether this would work in my situation.

It's also not possible to iterate through each byte and remove the first two items as python still treats the entire byte as one object.

Here is the list I have after appending it with both bytes:

[image]

While it looks like two strings, they do not behave as strings. I then iterated over the list using:

```
for x in a:
    print a
```

The two lines below the list are the outputs of 'print a' (a blank space & special character). As you can see they do not print as normal strings.

Below is a code snippet showing how I add the bytes to the array, nothing complicated (test being the array in this case).

```
for i in openFile.read(512):
    ....
    ....
    elif 10 < count < 13:
        test.insert(0, i[0:])
```

Comment: You're confusing the object itself with its string representation. A string of bytes can't contain 0x0200 because that wouldn't fit into 8 bits, it simply doesn't make sense. I think you need to be more specific about the output you want.

Comment: Sorry I'm finding hard to convey what I mean. I'm reading bytes from a file.. The first byte is '02' (`\x02`) in python. All I want to do is remove the `\x` from the byte in my list.

Comment: Please refer to the edit which will hopefully make the problem more clear.

Comment: @Calibre The byte does not actually contain `\x`, this is just notation to indicate that the character is unprintable.

Comment: Please post a code snippet showing how you obtain your list of one-byte strings, and what you want to do with them.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that a string can look different when printed depending upon whether it's in a list or not. For example, on my machine, `x = ['\x02']; print x; print x[0]` prints `['\x02']` followed by a happy face.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826284/how-do-i-convert-a-string-2-bytes-long-to-an-integer-in-python

Comment: You've shown what it's printing, but what do you *want* it to print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ord` to extract each character's numeric value, then combine them with simple arithmetic.

```
>>> a = '\x02'
>>> b = '\x00'
>>> c = ord(a)*256 + ord(b)
>>> c == 0x0200
True
>>> print hex(c)
0x200
```

Comment: This does not work either sadly as I need to preserve the zeroes and convert from hex to decimal. The two bytes are `\x02` and `\x00` I need to convert that into `0x0200` which translates to 512 in decimal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `c` _is_ 512 in decimal.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. But when I replicate the same actions when using bytes instead of strings, c != 0x0200.

Comment: It's strange, when I calculate the values of a & b from my list it works as you said. But when I calculate a & b from reading the bytes from the file, it does not.

Comment: @Calibre if you do `len(a)` or `len(b)` you'll see that they're all a single byte, even though it takes 4 characters to print the value.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, this makes it slightly more clear, I still don't understand why the above operation does not work when creating the variables straight from reading the bytes though.

Comment: FWIW, on my machine, the code also works on bytes. `ord(b'\x02') * 256 + ord(b'\x00')` gives 512 as expected.

Comment: As it does on mine, god knows why it didn't want to work straight from the file. Thanks for your help Kevin you have helped me towards solving the issue.

Comment: Is there any reason you can think why it would be this way? I'm getting the bytes from the boot sector of an NTFS partition if that would make any difference

Comment: Just to clarify, by declaring the bytes in-line as you did in your example, it works and returns 512/True(for 0x0200). However when I declare a & b directly from the file it returns 2/False(for 0x0200).

Comment: I wonder if there's some kind of weird endianness problem going on there. Because 2 would be the result of `ord(b'\x00') * 256 + ord(b'\x02')`.

Comment: Of course.. I was correcting the endianness (little-endian on my machine) with the list using `insert(0, i)` but I was forgot to correct it when declaring a & b. My silly mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much though, you sir are a genius & have helped me a lot!

Comment: @Kevin when applying this to a larger number of bytes (8 for example) how would the code be modified to account for that?

Comment: I guess you could do `seq = ['\x02', '\x00', insert_rest_of_values_here]; result = sum(ord(x)<<8*i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(seq)))`

Answer (score 3):

An alternate way to do this for standard-length types is to use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to convert from strings of bytes to Python types.

For example:

```
>>> import struct
>>> byte_arr = ['\x02', '\x00']
>>> byte_str = ''.join(byte_arr)
>>> byte_str
'\x02\x00'
>>> num, = struct.unpack('>H', byte_str)
>>> num
512
```

In this example, the format string `'>H'` indicates a big-endian unsigned 2-byte integer.  Other format strings can be used to specify other sizes, endianness, and signed/unsigned status.

Comment: This seems very clean and looks to work as desired. I will give it some more research tomorrow, thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

```
new_str=str(your_byte_like_object).split('\\x')
print("".join(new_str))
```

You can convert the byte object to str and split it separator use \x 
and you get a list and join it.

that's all.

output is like this:

`eigioer #text`

```
b'0\x1e\xd7\xe8\xdf\xc1\xd7\x90o3`mD\x92U\xf5\xca\xe7l\xe5"TM' #raw byte
```

```
["b'0", '1e', 'd7', 'e8', 'df', 'c1', 'd7', '90o3`mD', '92U', 'f5', 'ca', 'e7l', 'e5"TM\''] #list
```

```
b'01ed7e8dfc1d790o3`mD92Uf5cae7le5"TM' #after joining
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had a "bytes" object and I needed to remove the `\x`s to be able to upload my file to Cassandra, and all I needed to do was to use this:

```
my_bytes.hex()
```

Answer (score -2):

We know that it always starts with \x, and the 'it' is a string. So we can just do...

```
>>> num = "\\x02"
>>> num = num[2:]
>>> print num
02
```

Update:

```
>>> num = [r"\x02", r"\x20"]
>>> num = [ n[2:] for n in num ]
>>> num
['02', '20']
```

Comment: I think the OP has `\x02` rather than `\\x02`.

Comment: It's not a string sadly, and does not let me use string functions such as this.

Comment: If you wanted to use this solution, you can use the str() function.

Comment: Have already tried the str() function, it doesn't work sorry. I've tried this method and it doesn't convert from the byte and still treats it as a single object, not letting me iterate through.

Comment: I don't quite understand. There is no byte type in python. Do you mean to say that you have a string of 'bytes' and they are noted like this? '\x02\x20'? You can use the split function if that's the case. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Please refer to my edit, there's an image which shows the content of the list, and then the result of printing each item within the list. I want them to behave as they are displayed in the list, not as how they are printed. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do me a quick favor and `print type(data)`. If it's a list, run `print type(data[0])`

Comment: It returns '<type 'str'>. Which confuses me even further since it does not print as if it's a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72260/discussion-between-calibre-and-profoak).

Comment: I've updated my solution to account for lists. I'll reply later if you have more questions.